# Media Player Classic plays everything stretched/zoomed

Tags: video, zoom, media-player-classic, stretch

The program sudenly started playing all videos very stretched or zoomed, not even changing the pan/scan, zoom and the like works. I re-installed my video drivers, CCCP and MPC-HC. But it persists.
The programs behaves like the stretched picture is the standard video size.

[image: screengrab]

Answer (score 2):

You might have accidentally hit a keyboard combination for a zoom effect. Note that with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> *on*, the *Number Keypad* affects postion and zoom. Right-click on the screen while playing a video, and note that there are multiple pop-up menu items affecting zoom and aspect ratio:

1. *Zoom*: proportional size
2. *Video Frame*: both zoom level and **aspect ratio**, which appears to be the issue you experience
3. *Pan & Scan*: Also affects **aspect ratio**

You may need to experiment with the last two settings, or choose *Reset* where available, to resolve the issue.

Though I really like MPC-HC, the plethora of menu items can be confusing!

BTW, MPC-HC inherits from MPC, but [Media Player Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Player_Classic) (*not* Home Cinema) is a different application.